# Changing UISlider x and y position

Tags: ios, swift, uislider, cgrectmake

I have viewController with slider inside and I need to change the position of slider programmatically. I am using following code:

```
mySliderOutlet.frame = CGRectMake(100, 250, mySliderOutlet.frame.size.width, mySliderOutlet.frame.size.height)
```

Problem is this doesn't do anything. Outlet is connected correctly, I am using it elsewhere in the code to read values from slider. I will be glad for any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: That code is just the frame for the slider. Are you seeking to change the position of the frame or of the slider within the frame?

Comment: I am not sure what to answer. I need to change the position of slider in viewController. I thought that can be done by changing the frame. Am I wrong?

Comment: you are trying to change the disposition of your slider from horizontal to vertical?

Comment: Yes, I am. Is that a problem?

Comment: @otter you need this on Objective-C or Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure, following this are done before setting the frames on your slider

1. Autolayout is turned off and sizing classes are disabled in the storyboard.[Here is how to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50IZc.png)
2. Turn off the 'auto resize subview' for the view inside the viewcontroller from storybaord.[Uncheck the autoresize subview option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WZ49.png)
3. Make sure this frame update your'e doing must be done in Main thread or main queue.

Comment: Yes, this does the trick. But I was hoping there is a way to move slider around and still be able to use constraints. Is there a way to do it? Anyway thanks a lot. I am gonna use this solution.

Comment: if you want to keep constraint in storyboard and still want to update the frame or bound from the code, you need to take the outlet of the constraintss and update their status from the code.

Answer (score 0):

With `AffineTransform` you can rotate your `UISlider` `layer` try this code for this results

[image]

### Swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var verticalSlider: UISlider!
    func DEGTORAD(deg:Double) -> CGFloat
    {
      return CGFloat(deg * M_PI / 180.0)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        verticalSlider.layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGTORAD(90)))
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you, but this isn`t what I need. I know how to rotate slider, my problem is I need to move it. @RatulSharker gave me an answer.

Comment: @otter, You can change the constraints constant values to move your UISlider to any position you want to